# Entity Base Class Library

Tags: .net, base-class

Is there as base class library out there with entities like customer, address, order etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "base class library" as in the libraries that ship with the .NET framework, then the answer is no. Usually that sort of thing is too application specific to be useful to more than one person. I mean, although a lot of apps have similarities, they also have a lot of small (or large) differences.